# Different Logging Mechanisms available on Ruby on rails3 for a vast application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I need a suggestion on the best logging mechanism available out of all for a vast application which may need something like log4j..

Comment: This is a rather broad and subjective question. Please specify what it is you exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails already comes with a logger. Of course you can substitute it for another logger, for which Log4r (has quite some similarities with log4j) could be a good option. But it would be nice if you could elaborate a bit more, before asking one-line questions. Anyway, this is a great place to start:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Chapter 2 covers the (built-in Ruby) logger.